# ¿Se puede hacer migracion con laravel sin perder los datos de las tablas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo mis tablas echas directamente desde laravel, pero cuando modifico alguna, para agregar un campo o quitarlo, al momento de hacer la `migracion` con laravel, pierdo todos los datos que poseen las tablas, hay alguna forma de hacer estas migraciones sin perder los datos?, ya que no me parecio encontrar nada al respecto en la documentacion oficial.

Tabla Users

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('last_name');
            $table->integer('ci')->unique();
            $table->date('birthdate');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

        });

        Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table){

            $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

Tabla Roles

```
class CreateRolesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

            $table->increments('id');
            $table->char('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('roles');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo correcto en este caso es crear una nueva migración para modificar la tabla, por ejemplo, agregar un campo "hobby" en la tabla users:

```
class AddHobbyFieldUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {

            $table->string('hobby')->nullable();

        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('hobby');
        });
    }
}
```

Una vez creada la nueva migración, la ejecutas y no pierdes ningún valor existente en la tabla, sin embargo siempre es obligatorio hacer backup antes de una migración.

Comment: Y en este caso, que comando de artisan lanzo para que realize unicamente esta migracion, porque `php artisan migrate`, me lo hara en todas las tablas

Comment: Si usas `php artisan migrate`, ejecutaré las migraciones que estén pendientes, si quieres ejecutar una específicamente, utiliza `php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/AddHobbyFieldUsersTable`

Comment: Listo hermano, muchas gracias